# click the delete button click all of grid in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to delete row button click delete button. I can't delete only the selected row, it deleted the full grid, and after did not display the  grid. How can i fix delete selected row ?

Before delete:

[image: before delete]

After delete:

[image: After delete]

**code**

```
protected void btnDeleteOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtItems = new DataTable();
    dtItems.Columns.Add("RowId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("ItemId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("Percentage", typeof(decimal));
    dtItems.Columns.Add("LabDipId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("RecipeId");

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gdDyeNames.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtPercentage = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtPercentage");
        DropDownList ddlDyeingType = ((DropDownList)gr.FindControl("ddlDyeingType"));

        DataRow dr = dtItems.NewRow();

        dr["RecipeId"] = SelectedReciptId;
        dr["ItemId"] = int.Parse(ddlDyeingType.SelectedValue.ToString());
        dr["Percentage"] = decimal.Parse(txtPercentage.Text).ToString();
        dtItems.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    DataRow[] drItem = dtItems.Select("ItemId = " + selectedRowId);

    foreach (DataRow dr in drItem)
    {
        dtItems.Rows.Remove(dr);
    }

    gdDyeNames.DataSource = dtItems;
    gdDyeNames.DataBind();

    lblEror.Text = "";
    lblMsg.Text = "";
    mpdelete.Hide();
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `DataRow[] drItem` after you select. maybe is your select cause.

Comment: Why are you recreating a new table, shouldn't you just use the existing one, can we see the bindings for the DataTable, then it would make more sence of that you are trying to do.

Comment: sir, im removed and try it, but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i develop it ,thats work fine

```
if (dtItems != null)
            {
                ImageButton imb = sender as ImageButton;
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(imb.CommandArgument);


                if (dtItems.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dtItems.Rows.Remove(dtItems.Rows[rowIndex]);

                    gdDyeNames.DataSource = dtItems;
                    gdDyeNames.DataBind();

                    lblEror.Text = "";
                    lblMsg.Text = "";
                    mpdelete.Hide();

                    if (dtItems.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        createIntialGrid();
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
protected void btnDeleteOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtItems = new DataTable();
    dtItems.Columns.Add("RowId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("ItemId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("Percentage", typeof(decimal));
    dtItems.Columns.Add("LabDipId");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("RecipeId");

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gdDyeNames.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtPercentage = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtPercentage");
        DropDownList ddlDyeingType = ((DropDownList)gr.FindControl("ddlDyeingType"));

        DataRow dr = dtItems.NewRow();

        dr["RecipeId"] = SelectedReciptId;
        dr["ItemId"] = int.Parse(ddlDyeingType.SelectedValue.ToString());
        dr["Percentage"] = decimal.Parse(txtPercentage.Text).ToString();
        dtItems.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


        ImageButton btnDetails = (ImageButton)sender; //Change Image button to your Button used
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnDetails.NamingContainer;
        int rowIndex = row.RowIndex; 
        DataRow dr = dtItems.Rows[rowIndex];
        dtItems.Rows.Remove(dr);
        dtItems.AcceptChanges();

    gdDyeNames.DataSource = dtItems;
    gdDyeNames.DataBind();

    lblEror.Text = "";
    lblMsg.Text = "";
    mpdelete.Hide();
}
```

Comment: error for this `DataRow dr = dtItems.Rows[rowIndex];`

Comment: you please check the value integer 'rowIndex'. If value of rowIndex is present in dtItems row index then you must get the corresponding row. And it's better to use a ViewState to store your datatable.   You must study little more on debugging.

Comment: ViewState["List1"] = dtItems;

Comment: retrive by. DataTable dtItems =(DataTable)ViewState["List1"];